# Securing travis ci environmental variables in a open-source project for system testing

Tags: node.js, testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci, system-testing

I'm building an open-source library that provides an API for a 3rd party service. During which I'm learning testing, git-flow and continuous deployment and came across an problem related to securing environmental variables for open-source project.

I currently have generated secret environment variables through the travis cli: 
`travis encrypt key=value`, that are used for automated system testing.

On pushing updates to feature branches or pull-requests noticed that tests are automatically ran by travis ci, which is awesome. But I started to wonder what protects my against someone making a pull requests that maliciously gathers the `process.env` object and pushes it to something external, thus revealing my precious environmental variables.

**How does one truly be sure that environment credentials (such as API credentials) are protected in travis ci for system testing?**

**Should I even by creating system tests?** Or should I fake the requests to the external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis CI documentation says:

> For the protection of secure data, Travis CI makes it available only
>   on pull requests coming from the same repository. These are considered
>   trustworthy, as only members with write access to the repository can
>   send them.
>
> Pull requests sent from forked repositories don’t have this data
>   available in their builds. All data that’s considered confidential
>   will not be added to the build’s environment.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests#Security-Restrictions-when-testing-Pull-Requests